# Creating a visible grid in a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, graphics

#### What I'm trying to do

I want to create an API (personal one) that allows me to input a dimension (say 10x10) and it creates a visible grid with 10 squares by 10 squares, with the added 'feature' of being able to change the fill of any of the squares via a method call.  Not trying to use a `mouse listener` or any `listener`s of any sort.

My thought process is something like this:
Have the main `JPanel` that holds the grid recursively add 'box' `objects` and reference each one with an `array` location.  My issue isn't the main `JPanel`, that I've got down easily enough.  My issue is the `object` it's adding.  I can't figure out what sort of `component` this should be.  I attempted using a `JPanel` but couldn't get anything to be visible.  Besides, the 'grid' look wouldn't be there either.

I'm guessing I'm going to have to utilize `swing.Graphics` or `Graphics2D` but every example I've found online hasn't worked out well for me.  Looking for advice on using `Graphics`, or if there's an even better way of getting what I want, I'd gladly try it out.

Comment: Why not use JTable? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html

Comment: For the kind of thing you are describing Graphics might not be that bad an idea... just get the graphics of the JPanel and start drawing to it.. also I'm not seeing where the recursion is coming from...

Comment: @user3334690  Because I'd like to be able to pass in 'change grid 3x10' (in a 10x10 grid) without having to find the plot points.  In other words, reference the object directly.

Comment: @Eric no matter what you do, something somewhere had to do the drawing, it's just a question of what level you want to mess around in...  I personally find that sometimes re-inventing the wheel on some of these simpler things can be very educational

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Have a `MainPanel` class that takes the dimension arugments and set it's layout to `GridLayout` based on the  specified dimension

   ```
   public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
       public MainPanel(int rows, int cols) {
           setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));
       }
   }
   ```
2. Create an interface that has a `draw()` method

   ```
   public interface Drawable {
       void draw(Graphics g);
   }
   ```
3. Create a custom panel that has a `Drawable` property, in which you will call it's draw method

   ```
   public class DrawPanel extends JPanel {
       private Drawable drawable;

       public DrawPanel() {}

       public DrawPanel(Drawable drawable) {
           this.drawable = drawable;
       }

       public void setDrawable(Drawable drawable) {
           this.drawable = drawable;
           repaint();
       }

       @Override
       protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
           super.paintComponent(g);
           if (drawable != null) {
               drawable.draw(g);
           }
       }
   }
   ```
4. Create a 2D array of your `DrawPanels` in the `MainPanel` class, just you you can access them by index, if you need to to

   ```
   public class MainPanel extends JPanel {
       private DrawPanel[][] panels;
       public MainPanel(int rows, int cols) {
           setLayout(new GridLayout(rows, cols));
           panels = new DrawPanel[rows][cols];
       }
   }
   ```
5. Populate the array with `new DrawPanel`s and add them to the `MainPanel`

   ```
   for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++) {
       for (int j = 0; j < cols; j++) {
           DrawPanel panel = new DrawPanel();
           panels[i][j] = panel;
           MainPanel.this.add(panel);
       }
   }
   ```
6. Implement the `Drawable` interface with some whatever/how many implemtations you want. Like

   ```
   public class Ball implements Drawable {
       private int x, y;
       private JPanel surface;
       public Ball(int x, int y, JPanel surface) {
           this.x = x;
           this.y = y;
           this.surface = surface;
       }

       @Override
       public void draw(Graphics g) {
           g.fillOval(x, y, sirface.getWidth(), surface.getHeight());
       }
   }
   ```
7. Add you drawable object to a panel

   ```
   JPanel panel = panels[3][4];
   panel.setDrawable(new Ball(0, 0, panel));
   ```
8. You can make as many different implementations of `Drawable` as you want, and each panel can have a different object drawn.

   ```
   public class Midget implements Drawable {
       @Override
       public void draw(Graphics g) {
           // draw midget
       }
   }
   ....
   panels[5][5].setDrawable(new Midget());
   ```

Answer (score 2):

Try below sample code using `JLabel`

```
JPanel panel = new JPanel(new GridLayout(10, 10));
JLabel[] labels = new JLabel[20];

Color[] colors = new Color[] { Color.GREEN, Color.RED, Color.BLUE };
Random random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {
    JLabel label = new JLabel();

    label.setBackground(colors[random.nextInt(colors.length)]);
    label.setOpaque(true);

    panel.add(label);
    labels[i] = label;
}
```

snapshot:

[image]

Comment: I'm considering doing this and just adding a border to each label to simulate the grid lines.  Thanks.